# Can I change the overall width of the invoice package's table?

Tags: tables, formatting, width, invoice

I'm using `\usepackage{invoice}`, and I'm wondering if I can adjust the width of the table?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{invoice}
\date{September 1994}
\begin{document}
\begin{invoice}{USD}{0}
\ProjectTitle{Administrative Fees}
\Fee{Database Management}{1199.99}{3}
\EBC{Tolerating You}{1000.00}
\end{invoice}
\end{document}
```

---

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Jubobs, see my edit.

Comment: I think you're better off setting your *own* invoice manually *without* [`invoice`](http://ctan.org/pkg/invoice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I appears that the `\my@invoice` environment hard codes the width of the first column to be `5cm` and I don't see any easy way to adjust it, except to redefine the environment.

The following code provides a `\MyInvoiceWidth` which defaults to `5cm`, and can be modified with

```
\renewcommand*{\MyInvoiceWidth}{3cm}%
```

as is the case for the second table below.

[image]

### Notes:

- You can change the `longtable` specification as you desired.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{invoice}
\date{September 1994}

\newcommand*{\MyInvoiceWidth}{5cm}%
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{\my@invoice}[2]{%
    \setcounter{Fee@ctr}{0}%        % reset counter
    \setcounter{Expense@ctr}{0}%        % reset counter
    \def\Null{0}%
    \setcounter{Project}{0}%
    \ST@Reset\Total@Reset%
    \def\BC{#1}%
    \def\VAT@rate{#2}%
    \ifx\VAT@rate\Null\VATnonzerofalse\else\VATnonzerotrue\fi%
    \ifVATnonzero
        \message{^^J^^JVAT is not zero!^^J^^J}%
    \else
        \message{^^J^^JVAT is zero!^^J^^J}%
    \fi%
    % The VAT is: \the\VAT@rate % Debugging Diagnostics only
    \parindent=0cm%
    \ifcase\Flag % 0: Invoice not started yet
        %
        \gdef\Flag{1}%
        %\begin{center}% Removed 20050621 by suggestion from ...
        \begin{longtable}{p{\MyInvoiceWidth}lrrr}%
        %
    \else \error@message{\NoInvoiceNesting}%
    \fi}%
% At the end of environment: 
% Yields state 8->0, Close and complete invoice, finish tables, etc.
{% 
    \ifcase\Flag % 0: Invoice not started yet
        %
        \error@message{\MissingOpening}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 1: Start invoice
        %
        \error@message{\MissingProject}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 2: Start project, print title
        %
        \error@message{\MissingInputData}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 3: Print remuneration item
        %
        \ifnum\theProject>0 \ST@Fee\ST@Project\fi%
        \Tot@l%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 4: Print subtotal remuneration
        %
        \ifnum\theProject>1 \ST@Project\fi%
        \Tot@l%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 5: Expense item
        %
        \ifnum\theProject>1 \ST@Expenses\ST@Project\fi%
        \Tot@l%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 6: Print subtotal expenses
        %
        \ifnum\theProject>1 \ST@Project\fi%
        \Tot@l%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 7: Print subtotal project
        %
        \Tot@l%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 8: Print total, close invoice
        %
        \warning@message{\InvoiceCompleted}%
        %
    \else \error@message{\InternalError}%
    \fi%
    \gdef\Flag{0}%
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{invoice}{USD}{0}
\ProjectTitle{Administrative Fees}
\Fee{Database Management}{1199.99}{3}
\EBC{Tolerating You}{1000.00}
\end{invoice}

\renewcommand*{\MyInvoiceWidth}{3cm}%
\noindent
\begin{invoice}{USD}{0}
\ProjectTitle{Administrative Fees}
\Fee{Database Management}{1199.99}{3}
\EBC{Tolerating You}{1000.00}
\end{invoice}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So, you took the source code from the definition of `\invoice` and redefined parts of it within the to-be-compiled TeX source?

Comment: @HilbertNowak: Yep. Also have modified it now so that you can change the column width as desired from one invoice to the next. Similar customizations can be done for the other columns if desired.  The long term solution is that this kind of customization is provided by the package itself.

Comment: I'm actually using `\documentclass{letter}`; is there a difference? I ask because I've just added your `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` code just below `\documentclass{letter}`, but I get: "`!Undefined control sequence. <argument> \my@invoice l.67 \renewenvironment{\my@invoice}[2]{%`"

Comment: @HilbertNowak: There should be no difference in using `letter` class vs `article` related to this. Are you adding the `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` _after_ `\usepackage{invoice}`?

Comment: No, I just did. Now I get: "`!LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type H<return> for immediate help. ... l.21 \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]`"

Comment: In fact, this is what I'm working with: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174367/how-to-change-the-default-top-margin-for-an-invoice

Comment: @HilbertNowak: I'd suggest you post a followup up question as to why you can't use what I posed with the `letter` class -- and include a link to this one specifying that it is a follow up. Does it work with the `article` class for you?

Comment: Hi, thank you! Where did you find the source-code for this `.tex` file? I don't see it [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/invoice/).

Answer (score 2):

It is not that difficult to create your own "invoice" through some basic macros. Here's one try:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,std,fixed zerofill,precision=2,/pgf/fpu = true}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}

\newcommand{\invoicetitle}{Administrative Fees}
\newcommand{\invoicetitleformat}{\bfseries\large}
\newlength{\titleskip}\setlength{\titleskip}{\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\invoicecurrency}{USD}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{activity@num}
\newcommand{\activityitemtotal@}{0}
\newcommand{\activity}[3]{%
  \\
  \ifnum\value{activity@num}=0 \midrule\fi%
  \stepcounter{activity@num}%
  \pgfmathparse{#2 * #3}\global\let\activityitem@\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathparse{\activityitemtotal@ + \activityitem@}\global\let\activityitemtotal@\pgfmathresult%
  #1 & & \pgfmathprintnumber{#2} & #3 & \pgfmathprintnumber{\activityitem@}%
}
\newcounter{expense@num}
\newcommand{\expenseitemtotal@}{0}
\newcommand{\expense}[4][\invoicecurrency]{%
  \\
  \ifnum\value{expense@num}=0 \midrule\fi%
  \stepcounter{expense@num}%
  \pgfmathparse{#3 * #4}\global\let\expenseitem@\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathparse{\expenseitemtotal@ + \expenseitem@}\global\let\expenseitemtotal@\pgfmathresult%
  #2 & #1 & \pgfmathprintnumber{#3} & #4 & \pgfmathprintnumber{\expenseitem@}%
}
\newcommand{\activitytotal}{%
  Sum fees & & & & \pgfmathprintnumber{\activityitemtotal@}}
\newcommand{\expensetotal}{%
  Sum expenses & & & & \pgfmathprintnumber{\expenseitemtotal@}}
\newcommand{\totaltotal}{%
  \textbf{Total} & & & & %
    \pgfmathparse{\activityitemtotal@ + \expenseitemtotal@}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  {\invoicetitleformat\invoicetitle\par}\nobreak
  \vspace*{\titleskip}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Xlrrr}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Activity} & & Rate/Unit & Count & Amount (\invoicecurrency)
    \activity{Database management}{1199.99}{3}
    \activity{Office management}{123.45}{2}
    \activity{Product delivery}{6789.10}{2}
    \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
    \textbf{Expense} & Currency & Amount & Factor & \invoicecurrency
    \expense{Tolerating you}{1000.00}{1}
    \expense[CDN]{Office supplies}{12.00}{1.29}
    \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
    \midrule
    \activitytotal \\
    \expensetotal \\
    \bottomrule
    \totaltotal \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You'll note that the construction of the invoice is done using [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) with the width set to `\linewidth`. You can adjust this to (say) `.6\linewidth` to only take up 60% of the width of a line. Also, now you can freely adjust the column specification to suit your needs.

Of course, it depends on your varied usage of [`invoice`](http://ctan.org/pkg/invoice), but features can be added as needed. In the very least, I think it is more flexible that `invoice`.